# Is there a standalone chip/breakout to measure voltage and current to display externally

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I am currently looking for a DC voltage and current meter that I can put between my power source and the load. I can find a lot of packaged products that come with a display and everything, however I do not want to have that, I only want the circuitry maybe with 12V input, 12V output and grounds with an I/O interface (UART, SPI, I2C, whatever) to read the parameters from. First I was thinking about buying a already packaged meter, disassembling and then reverse engineer it, however I cant stop thinking that there is a better way and I am just not using the right search terms. Is there such a thing? And if so, what exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: There are standalone modules galore, from the usual sources.

Comment: Yes, such things exist. 

What exactly you are looking for, well, we're not supposed to do product recommendations here, but you may want to google "high side voltage and current sensor".

Comment: replacing the word "meter" in my search with "sensor" was magical!